# How to add to my lm regression formula a control for the dependent variable at (t-1)

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, regression, linear-regression

I'm structuring a simple linear regression model using `lm` and since I think that my dependent variable is history-dependent I would like to add a control variable that is the dependent variable at time (t-1).

How can I do that in R? This is my model so far:

```
lm(Y ~ Country + Year + GDP, data=df)
```

And I would like to add a control variable like so:

```
lm(Y ~ Y(t-1) + Country + Year + GDP, data=df)
```

I hope it is clear! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Can use `dplyr` library to add the control feature.

```
library(dplyr)

# create a new variable for the value of Y at time (t-1)
df$Y_lag <- lag(df$Y)

# run the regression with Y_lag as a control variable
fit <- lm(Y ~ Y_lag + Country + Year + GDP, data=df)
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Assuming that the data is in order of increasing time to align the variables appropriately remove the first or last element of each column.  We have used the built in BOD data frame since the input was not provided in the question -- see the info at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page for guidance on asking questions.

```
nr <- nrow(BOD)
lm(demand[-1] ~ Time[-1]  + demand[-nr], BOD)
```

**2)** Use flag from the collapse package.

```
library(collapse)
lm(demand ~ Time  + flag(demand), BOD)
```

**3)** An alternative is the dyn package.  In particular comparing models using `anova` is tricky when using lags but dyn has an `anova.dyn` which addresses these problems automatically.  Note that dplyr clobbers R's lag with its own lag and will result in dozens or hundreds of packages to fail so be sure that dplyr is not loaded or use `library(dplyr, exclkude = c("lag","filter"))` if you need dplyr.  This works with zoo and ts objects.

```
library(dyn)
z <- read.zoo(BOD, drop = FALSE)
dyn$lm(demand ~ time(z) + lag(demand, -1), z)
```

**4)** There is also the dynlm package which uses a slightly different syntax than dyn but is similar in prinicple. An important advantage of dynlm is that it supports instrumental variables regression via two-stage least squares.